# ios 9 facebook. Is this possible to continue to use 3.20 Facebook SDK, and continue to compile with iOS SDK 8?

Tags: ios, facebook, upgrade, ios9

Facebook features in our app stops work correctly on device running iOS 9.
We are using Facebook Unity SDK v6.2.2 (thus native Facebook SDK 3.20), and we compile with iOS SDK 8.
We already read Facebook's article about preparing for iOS 9. 
But we do not understand some moments.
Ideally, we want to continue to use 6.2.2/3.20 Facebook SDK, and continue to compile with iOS SDK 8. Is tihs possible?
Are there any legal ways for our app to continue working with Facebook on iOS 9  WITHOUT upgrading to latest Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible. We did that, and all is ok for now.